# Окно подтверждения при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте.

Есть скрипт, который ловит все обновления страницы (при нажатии на ссылку, при обновлении через <kbd>F5</kbd>, через <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> и т.д.) и перед обновлением появляется окно с сообщением что данные могут быть не сохранены. Нужно сделать для того, чтобы пользователь случайно не обновил страницу когда в форме есть текст.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку с `id="ms-submit-button"` окно не появлялось.

Пробовал сделать исключение с помощью *jQuery*, не получилось.

```
function Unloader(){

var o = this;

this.unload = function(evt)
{
    var message = "Данные не будут сохранены после обновления страницы или перехода";
        if($("#taskname").val() != "" || $(".note-editable").text()) { // проверка моих полей на пустоту
            if (typeof evt == "undefined") {
                evt = window.event;
            }
            if (evt) {
                evt.returnValue = message;
            }
            return message;
        }
    }

    this.resetUnload = function()
    {
        $(window).off('beforeunload', o.unload);

         setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
        }, 2000);
    }

    this.init = function()
    {

        $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);

        $('a').on('click', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){o.resetUnload});
        $(document).on('keydown', function(event){
            if((event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 116) || event.keyCode == 116){
                o.resetUnload;
            }
        });
    }
    this.init();
}

$(function(){
    if(typeof window.obUnloader != 'object')
    {
        window.obUnloader = new Unloader();
    }
})
```

Comment: @Yuri, ошибка была, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Та, я бы сам исправил, если бы понял что это :)

Comment: а сделать 'ручную' обработку `onclick` ссылке `id="ms-submit-button"`, в которой бы присвоить `null` или что-то другое `window.obUnloader`, а, затем, направить "вручную" по нужной ссылке?

Comment: Что то не получается у меня, поможете? `<a href="link" id="ms-submit-button" onclick="window.obUnloader=null">click</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я так понял, что вам нужен такой результат:

```js
function Unloader() {

  var o = this;

  this.unload = function(evt) {
    var message = "Данные не будут сохранены после обновления страницы или перехода";
    if ($("#taskname").val() != "" || $(".note-editable").text()) { // проверка моих полей на пустоту
      if (typeof evt == "undefined") {
        evt = window.event;
      };
      if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
      };
      return message;
    };
  };

  this.resetUnload = function() {
      $(window).off('beforeunload', o.unload);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
      }, 2000);
  };

  this.init = function() {

    $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);

    // Клик на a#ms-submit-button
    $('a#ms-submit-button').on('click', function() {
        $(window).off('beforeunload', o.unload);

        setTimeout(function() {
          $(window).on('beforeunload', o.unload);
        }, 2000);
    });
    
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
      o.resetUnload;
    });
    $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
      if ((event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 116) || event.keyCode == 116) {
        o.resetUnload;
      };
    });
  };
  this.init();
};

$(function() {
  if (typeof window.obUnloader != 'object') {
    window.obUnloader = new Unloader();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="/" id="ms-submit-button">Ссылка без подтверждения</a></p>
<p><a href="/">Ссылка с подтверждением</a></p>
```

Comment: Да, то что мне нужно. Спасибо вам А то я пробовал делать исключение с помощью jquery, вот так: `$('a:not(:has('#ms-submit-button'))').on('click', function() `

Comment: don't repeat yourself! =) `on('click', o.resetUnload)`

Comment: @Abmin, я тоже час пыхтел над этим вопросом. Думал, что тоже так можно сделать :)